# How to get different chart types in same plot

Tags: javascript, highcharts, r-highcharter

Is there any way to combine various chart-type like line+area in the `highchart` `js` package for `R`? I found a function as `hc_add_series()` but failed to understand how should I use this. Below are my codes -

```
   library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

Data = data.frame(date = seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()-20, by = '-1 day'), value1 = 10:30, variable = "A") %>% mutate(value2 = cumsum(value1))

hchart(Data, 
        "column", 
        hcaes(x = date, y = value1, group = variable)) %>%        
        hc_add_series(data = Data, hcaes(x = date, y = value2), type = 'area', yAxis = 1)
```

This actually plots nothing. Why exactly? I wanted to plot `value2` as `area` plot w.r.t. a `secondary axis` however that axis should remain `invisible`.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an `error 18` in the developer console which says that you connected the series to the axis that doesn't exist. And it's true - you connected series to the axis with index `1` by `yAxis: 1` but you haven't created that axis.

Generally, you don't need to create another axis. You can just remove this `yAxis: 1` and both series will be displayed:

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

Data = data.frame(date = seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()-20, by = '-1 day'), value1 = 10:30, variable = "A") %>% mutate(value2 = cumsum(value1))

hchart(Data, 
       "column", 
       hcaes(x = date, y = value1, group = variable)) %>%        
  hc_add_series(data = Data, hcaes(x = date, y = value2), type = 'area')
```

However, if that was intended and you do want to create separate axis for each series and display them separately, then let me know and I'll help you with that.

**edit:** here I created a second axis using `hc_yAxis_multiple`, I connected the area series to it and hid this axis:

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

Data = data.frame(date = seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()-20, by = '-1 day'), value1 = 10:30, variable = "A") %>% mutate(value2 = cumsum(value1))

hchart(Data, 
       "column", 
       hcaes(x = date, y = value1, group = variable)) %>%    
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(), # first yAxis
    list(visible = FALSE) # second yAxis
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = Data, hcaes(x = date, y = value2), type = 'area', yAxis = 1)
```

**edit 2:** here is an updated code adjusted to your new requirements. I set `tooltip.shared: true` (`hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE) %>%`) and set zIndex for a series:

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

Data = data.frame(date = seq(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()-20, by = '-1 day'), value1 = 10:30, variable = "Column") %>% mutate(value2 = cumsum(value1))

hchart(Data, 
       "column", 
       hcaes(x = date, y = value1, group = variable), zIndex = 1, opacity = 0.9) %>%  
  hc_tooltip(shared = TRUE) %>%
  hc_yAxis_multiples(
    list(), # first yAxis
    list(visible = FALSE) # second yAxis
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = Data, hcaes(x = date, y = value2), type = 'area', name = 'Area', yAxis = 1, zIndex = 0)
```

I additionally set opacity 0.9 on a column series, but you can remove it.

Comment: I wanted to create new axis for value2 as secondary but want to keep this axis invisible

Comment: I edited my answer. Could you confirm if this is what you were looking for?

Comment: many thanks. Is it possible to push the area chart behind the column chart and combine tootip for both into one? In that case, it may be prettier if we can have some sort vertical line along the cursor movement for combined tooltip

Comment: I edited my answer again ;) could you upvote it and mark as correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not much big difference, either you use R or Ruby on Rails for that customization.
To combine several chart types in one chart you only need to create series of different types:
When you instantiate Highcharts instance, you would be able to set `series` by revealing different type.

```html
 series: [{
type: 'column',
name: 'Jane',
data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4] },  {
type: 'column',
name: 'John',
data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6] },  {
type: 'column',
name: 'Joe',
data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0] },  {
type: 'spline',
name: 'Average',
data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33] }]
```

This is an example from official documentation.
As you can see in the code snippet, you are able to set what `type` you want to draw. e.g. `column`, `spline`, etc...
And set the `data` according to their type.

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo
https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/

But please note this solution is for Javascript.
You might want to see how you use this approach with `R`